# Performance degradation after migrating code block from IPython notebook cell to Python file

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Today I cleaned up an IPython notebook by pulling a large class definition out of a single cell in the notebook and placing it in a Python file which I later import. One thing I noticed after doing this is that the runtime performance of the notebook is significantly slower. The instance of the class created later in the notebook is called thousands of times during execution of the notebook. I don't understand what is behind the performance degradation. Any suggestions as to what might be behind this?

Comment: Have you tried to profile the code?  Are you doing anything except moving the code to another file?  Is your import / package structure correct?  What metrics are you using for "significantly slower"?  Any sort of benchmarks performed?  Where was the class before (in a method, dynamically generated only when necessary)?  There's too little detail here to help, IMHO.

Comment: Have you tried putting it back?

Comment: @g.d.d.c not yet. that's on tap for tomorrow.

Comment: @PeterWood I've got two versions of the notebook now. one with the class definition in a notebook cell. another with the code imported from a Python file. have just verified that the output statistics of the machine learning algorithm match across notebooks.

Comment: What changes did you have to make to the notebook? You need to show some code really. It is unlikely there is something wrong with IPython, and it's more likely something you're doing. Can you reproduce the issue with another class in another sheet? You're not giving us enough to go on and it's likely the question will be closed. If it's an issue with IPython, you need to show us how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PeterWood fair enough.